# Different results google indexed pages with php

Tags: php, google-api, google-index

I have this script to get google indexed pages of a url :

```
function getGoogleCount($domain) {
$content = file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/' .
    'search/web?v=1.0&filter=0&q=site:' . urlencode($domain));
$data = json_decode($content);
return intval($data->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount);
}

echo getGoogleCount('http://stackoverflow.com/');
```

But it not let me to get data for more urls. Then i used some online tools and result is different from mine. Is there other way to get these data without restrictions ?
Thanks.

Comment: You will need to explain "But it not let me to get data for more urls" what happens? do you get an error?

Comment: Yes. It works only for first 'echo' for other urls tell call to undefiened object on return intval. Maybe api has some restriction ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about calling `getGoogleCount` in a loop?

```
$domains = array('domain 1', 'domain 2');

foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    echo getGoogleCount($domain);
}
```